# draw arc from 0 to 360 degrees with d3.js

Tags: math, d3.js

YOu can see a working example of this [here](http://www.d3geometry.com/sine2).

My questions is about the small inner blue arc.  I want to show the arc starting at 0 and going to hypotenuse from 0 to 360.

At the moment m code looks like this that adds the arc:

```
const hypotenuseCoords = {
  x1: hypotenuseCentre,
  y1: parseFloat(state.hypotenuse.attr('y1')),
  x2: xTo,
  y2: dy
};

const angle = Math.atan2(hypotenuseCoords.y2 - hypotenuseCoords.y1, hypotenuseCoords.x2 - hypotenuseCoords.x1);

const arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(15)
        .outerRadius(20)
        .startAngle(Math.PI/2)
        .endAngle(angle + Math.PI/2);

state.innerAngle
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${hypotenuseCentre}, 0)`);
```

The problem is that the arc only goes from 0 to pi or 180 and from 180 to 360.  I think the startAngle in my coordinates is wrong.

How can I get the arc to stretch right round from 0 to 360?

Comment: nice wrok. you got a working fiddle we can edit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you calculate `angle`, try:

```
if(angle>0)
    angle = -2*(Math.PI) + angle;
```

If my trig is right :)

Update: Play with this fiddle to see the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/rcb94j8m/

`atan2()` was behaving fine for rays in quadrants 1 and 2, but was giving you trouble in quadrants 3 and 4. The `-2*(Math.PI)` shift gets you to the same ray, but going the other direction. Some studying of sign conventions with `atan2()` and `d3.svg.arc()` would probably lead you to a better explanation. I would be interested to read your conclusions, if you post them here.

Comment: Your trig is spot on.  Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @dagda1 I added a short explanation.

Comment: I'm going to blog about this.  I'll post the link when I am finished

Comment: Cool. It's a pretty neat visualization.